# Is there a python module that allows me to control my mouse without occupying the curser? i.e have 3 simultaneous cursers

Tags: python, dictionary, bots

I am open to any solutions though i would prefer python as i'm comfortable using it. I want a way to be able to control my mouse functions without using my curser, up until now i have used the pyautogui module but that isnt satisfactory as it uses my curser. I want to be able to play bluestacks on my computer, but the game i wish to make the bot for required multiple inputs (i.e move left and jump at the same time which required 2 simultaneous touch and hold inputs), so erratically teleporting the curser back and forward isn't appropriate. I have looked into Autohotkey, which although somewhat lets me do this using the 'controlclick' function, requires me to specify the window which i am having a hard time with because its an ungodly pain programming this parameter when i need it (Its not working for me, i would prefer either another solution, or else a way to generalise controlclick to only use coordinate parameters). As i say id prefer python, but any solution may be viable. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever seen two mouse curs**o**rs on a computer?

Comment: pyautogui is a good package for controlling mouse movements and finding buttons on the screen but idk if it can do multiple inputs. I think what you want to look up is "bluestacks multitouch"